# JavaScript: make selection.createRange function cross-browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, getselection

I am using the following line as part of a function to replace a selected text (selTxt) which works fine in IE.

selTxt comes from a different function which already works perfect for all browsers so the only part missing is to adapt the below. 
With "cross-browser" I mean Firefox and Chrome (besides IE) and only focus on current versions.

**Code line (working in IE):**

```
document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<strong>" + selTxt + "</strong>");
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: For starters: [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), then continue with [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range).

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the selected text in all browsers (selTxt) I only need to know how I can get the above replacement working cross-browser.

Comment: Hmm... That depends also, which HTML element is containing the selection. Tim Down's [Rangyinputs](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) could be a solution?